# Tag Combination

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337). Title based on [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/575/).</sup>

---

[construction](/questions/tagged/construction)
[computer-puzzle](/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle)
[number-theory](/questions/tagged/number-theory)
[tribond](/questions/tagged/tribond)
[weighing](/questions/tagged/weighing)
[pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern)
[calculation-puzzle](/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle)
[no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers)
[algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm)
[limerick](/questions/tagged/limerick)
[rubiks-cube](/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube)
[english](/questions/tagged/english)

---

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> construction
> CO
> computerpuzzle
>   M
> numbertheory
>    B
> tribond
>   I
> weighing
>       N
> pattern
>  A
> calculationpuzzle
>        T
> nocomputers
>    O
> algorithm
>     RI
> limerick
>       C
> rubikscube
>      S
> english
> ```
>
> Taking adjacent tags, we look at which letters are shared in the same position, with any hyphens removed. The shared letters give the answer **COMBINATORICS**. (Which is also a tag in of itself: [combinatorics](/questions/tagged/combinatorics))

Comment: Given the nature of the puzzle, I think the answer should be ,E28i4@>3:?2E@C:4D. (ROT 47) , right?

Answer (score 4):

An ironic answer given the last tag and open to critique:

> combinatoires

which pairs with the tag combinations by,

> **co**nstruction = co
>  c**om**puter-puzzle = om
>  nu**mb**er-theory = mb
>  tr**ib**nd = bi
>  weigh**in**g  = in
>  p**a**tter**n** = na
>  calcul**at**ion-puzzle = at
>  no-c**o**mpu**t**ers = to
>  alg**o**r**i**thm = oi
>  lime**ri**ck = ir
>  **r**ubiks-cub**e** = re
>  **e**ngli**s**h

Supplement:

> combinatories (rare) fits by the same method but combinatorics needs [chess](/questions/tagged/chess)instead of [english](/questions/tagged/english).

Comment: On the right track, but unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @noedne  - when I can't solve a puzzle sometimes I feel like asking for the question to be altered!